# How to listen to Server Side events for Facebook live comments on IOS

Tags: swift, server-sent-events, facebook-comments, facebook-live-api

I'm using the new SSE endpoints for Live comments on Live videos. my question is how can I achive this on IOS and what library should I use

I tried using the Event Source for IOS https://github.com/inaka/EventSource

But Even though I tried to use OnMessage and addOnEventsource it dosent seem to work.

Here is my code for listening to the live comments

```
    var live_commentURL =  URL.init(string:"https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/\(fbLiveStreamId!)/live_comments?access_token=\(accessToken ?? "")&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message")


        let queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: accessToken!), NSURLQueryItem(name: "comment_rate", value: "one_hundred_per_second"),NSURLQueryItem(name: "fields", value: "from{name,id},message")]
        let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: "https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/\(fbLiveStreamId!)/live_comments")!
//        var headders:[String:String] = [:]
//        headders["access_token"] = accessToken!
//        headders["comment_rate"] = "one_hundred_per_second"
//        headders["fields"] = "from{name,id},message"

        var eventSource = EventSource.init(url:urlComps.url!)
        eventSource.connect()
        eventSource.onOpen {
            print("Successfully Connected to server")
        }
        eventSource.addEventListener("user-connected") {(id, event, data) in
            print("id:", id)
            print("event:" , event)
            print("data: ", data)
        }

        eventSource.onMessage { (id, event, data) in
            print("id:", id)
            print("event:" , event)
            print("data: ", data)
        }
        print(eventSource.events())
        eventSource.onComplete { (code, isErro, error) in
            print(code)
        }
```

I have tried to send the access tokesn and other fields in headders too but got no luck with it.

I tried 2 methods

**method 1** 
send accesstoken,comment_rateand fields as headders but I dont think that is the right way.

**method 2**

Since they are all query params I used NSURLComponents.

Comment: Hi! When you're listening to the comments, and someone besides you comments on your livestream, did you can get the name and id of the person that had commented? I can get the comments, but can't identify who made the comment. Thanks.

Comment: @JorgeNachtigall if you want the user who has commented on the live stream you need to have them allow permissions to your Facebook app hence it would make sense if you create a group and invite people to that group where all the users can accept your apps permissions.

Comment: @MahiTejGvp your sample code is working, check your auth token

Comment: How did you disconnect server? 
By doing `eventSource.disconnect()` is now working. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with my auth tokens My bad